# A-Frame Camera Collision Issue with Objects

Tags: three.js, collision-detection, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I'm facing a challenge with A-Frame (version 1.4.0) regarding camera collision in my virtual reality scene. Despite employing various techniques such as using the collide attribute, integrating a raycaster for the camera, and exploring other potential solutions, I'm still unable to prevent the camera from passing through objects in the scene.

**What I've Tried:**
I applied the collide attribute to the a-box entity, and simultaneously, I experimented with a raycaster for the camera entity. Despite these efforts, the camera still passes through the objects in the A-Frame scene without the expected collision behavior.

**What I Expect:**
I expect the camera to collide with objects in the A-Frame scene, ensuring it doesn't pass through them and delivering a realistic virtual reality experience. However, the current behavior doesn't show the anticipated collision detection.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-extras/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-box position="0 0 -5" rotation="0 45 0" scale="2 2 2" collision color="tomato"></a-box>
        <a-sky color="#EEEEFF" material="src: ./sky.jpg" geometry=""></a-sky>
        <a-entity id="cameraEntity" camera="" universal-controls="" kinematic-body=""
            mouse-controls="pointerlockEnabled: false" data-aframe-inspector-original-camera="" position="0 1.6 0"
            grabbable look-controls wasd-controls>
            <a-entity id="cursorImage" cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 1000" position="0 0 -1"
                scale="0.00001 0.00001 0.00001" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
                material="color: red; shader: flat" light="type: ambient; intensity: 1.2" raycaster="">
            </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the code I tried. I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to effectively implement camera collision in A-Frame to address this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using the latest versions of A-Frame and aframe-extras. You mentioned using A-Frame 1.4.0, but your HTML snippet includes version 1.2.0. Updating these might bring in bug fixes or improved features that could help with collision detection.